# RegEx for extracting internal link in anchor tag and append something into it

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I develop a server-side rendering blog using Nuxt.js, I want to add the AMP version of this site. If the URL of the regular page is `https://example.com/blog/internal-link`, the AMP version will be `https://example.com/amp/blog/internal-link`.

I should append `/amp` prefix for all the internal link before it sends to the client if someone opens the AMP version.

I've got this regex `<a([^>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])([^\2]*?)\2\1*>` to extract the href value of the anchor tag.

Then I came up with this script:

```js
const regex = /<a([^>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])([^\2]*?)\2\1*>/gi;
const str = `<a href="/blog/internal-link" aria-label="Internal Link" class="blog__link">`;
const subst = `<a href="/amp$3>`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

But the regex above is extracted all the href value, including the external and internal link. How do I make the RegEx only match the internal link, suppose the internal link always like this `/blog/internal-link`?

So, based on that scenario, the input and the expected output should be like this:

Input: `<a href="/blog/internal-link" aria-label="Internal Link" class="blog__link">`

Output: `<a href="/amp/blog/internal-link" aria-label="Internal Link" class="blog__link">`

Input: `<a href="https://example.com/blog/internal-link" aria-label="Internal Link" class="blog__link">`

Output: `<a href="https://example.com/blog/internal-link" aria-label="Internal Link" class="blog__link">`

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for helping me to solve this problem. I end up using this RegEx
`<a([^>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])(\/[^\2]*?)\2\1*>`. I only need to add `\/` before `[^2]*?` to filter the internal link.

Here is the minimal reproduction with the final result for my problem:

```js
const html = `
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/blog/internal-link" aria-label="Internal Link" class="blog__link">Internal Link</a>
        <a href="https://example.com/blog/external-link" aria-label="External Link" class="blog__link">External Link</a>
    </body>
</html>`

const regex = /<a([^>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])(\/[^\2]*?)\2\1*>/gi;

const result = html.replace(regex, `<a href="/amp$3">`);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by making sure `/blog/internal-link` is part of your regex:

```js
const regex = /<a([^>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])([\s\S]*)\/blog\/([\s\S]*)([^\2]*?)\2\1*>/gi;
const str = `<a href="https://example.com/blog/internal-link" aria-label="Internal Link" class="blog__link">`;
const subst = `<a href="$3/blog/amp/$4>`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the link doesnt have to be `/blog/internal-link`, I just make an example by using that way, so the RegEx must be as flexsible as possible

Comment: "as flexsible as possible" is very vague. You have to give some examples if I can help you with making it more flexible.

Comment: Sorry for that, I mean the link can be anything as long as the internal link. And in my case, the internal link is like `/blog/internal-link` not `https://example.com/blog/internal-link`, although https://example.com is my domain.

Comment: I've made it more flexible so it will use whatever is before `/blog` and include that again when replacing and then whatever is after `\blog` and also include that with `\amp` at the beginning. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks, @Todd Chaffee your answer inspires me to get the right answer that fits in my case. :)

Comment: @JefryDewangga in that case could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `URL` class:

```
const href = str.match(/<a([^>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])([^\2]*?)\2\1*>/gi)[0]
const url = new URL(href, "http://example.com")
url.pathname = "/amp"+url.pathname

const newUrl = url.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using the RegEx with `match()` result an array contains only one item which is the original string.